# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given when variable "IS AN ARRAY"

Tags: arrays, wordpress

The code:

```
$cats = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
for ($i=0; $i < count($cats); $i++) { 
            printf(
                    '<option value="%s" %s style="margin-bottom:3px;">%s</option>',
                    $cats[$i]->term_id,
                    in_array( $cats[$i]->term_id, $categ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
                    $cats[$i]->name
            );
        }
```

var_dumping the $categ variable: `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "2" }`

when i say var_dumping it means var_dumping everywhere, outside the for loop, inside, always array.
Can someone tell me how in hell PHP is giving me this warning??

EDIT

The whole form() method:
and the var_dump is as you see, before the p tag with the fields and also after the foreach loop, both outputting an array

```
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ]; }
    else {
        $title = __( 'Latest Posts', 'di-news-blog' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance ['numPost'] ) ) {
        $numPost = $instance[ 'numPost' ]; }
    else {
        $numPost = __( 3 , 'di-news-blog' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance ['categ'] ) ) {
        $categ = $instance[ 'categ' ];
         }
    else {
        $categ = __( 'All categories' , 'di-news-blog' );
    }
    $cats = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
    // Widget admin form
     var_dump($categ); ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'di-news-blog' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numPost' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts:' , 'di-news-blog' ); ?></label> 
    <input style="margin-top: 15px" class="tiny-text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numPost' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'numPost' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $numPost ); ?>" size="3"><br><br>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'categ' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select categories:' , 'di-news-blog' ); ?></label> 
    <select  multiple style="height:200px" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'categ' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'categ' );?>[]">
        <option value="" style="margin-bottom:3px;"><?php _e('All categories', 'di-news-blog') ?></option>
    <?php 
        for ($i=0; $i < count($cats); $i++) { 
            printf(
                    '<option value="%s" %s style="margin-bottom:3px;">%s</option>',
                    $cats[$i]->term_id,
                    in_array( $cats[$i]->term_id, $categ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
                    $cats[$i]->name
            );
         }
         var_dump($categ);  ?>  

    </select>
    </p>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Post the code where `$categ` is initialised, and any/all interactions with it between then and the code above. Also, what's the `var_dump($categ)` output immediately above the `printf` statement?

Comment: Post edited with the whole form() method with two var_dumps, both outputting an array. Even if I choose the "All categories" option it's an array of one element.

Comment: You're setting `$categ = __( 'All categories' , 'di-news-blog' );`. This is a `string`, **not** an `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated post, when a category is not selected, you set `$categ` to a `string` value, and this is the cause of the warning.

```
$categ = __( 'All categories' , 'di-news-blog' );
```

Without knowing more about the purpose of the `<select>` field, it's difficult to advise further. But one option might be to set `$categ` to an empty array where not category is selected.

Comment: But the problem occurred with categories selected and the variable being an array.... ¿? As I told you even without categories selected the variable is an array[0]=>''; Anyways I'll try that tomorrow and log back then. Thanks!!

Comment: You got it fubar!!. SOLVED. I really couldn't imagine an error happening because of a portion of code inside an if statement that is not being executed. But apparently that matters in the end.